# scratch org is getting created on cci task run robot command

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, selenium, cumulusci

[image][image]I am trying to run a robot test on CircleCI using the command cci task run robot, but it is creating the fresh org again as it executes.

I am using below commands,

*venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev
venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites robot/tests/Activities.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome*

**CircleCI Yml**

```
 version: 2  orbs:   
win: circleci/windows@1.0.0 jobs: # A basic unit of work in a run   
build: # runs not using Workflows must have a `build` job as entry point 
        # directory where steps are run
        working_directory: ~/repo
        docker: # run the steps with Docker
          # CircleCI Python images available at: https://hub.docker.com/r/circleci/python/
          - image: circleci/python:3.7.2
            environment: # environment variables for primary container
              CUMULUSCI_KEYCHAIN_CLASS: cumulusci.core.keychain.EnvironmentProjectKeychain   steps: # steps that comprise the `build` job
          - checkout 
     - run:
                 name: Install Python deps in a venv
                 command: |
                     virtualenv venv                 
                     venv/bin/pip install -r requirements_dev.txt
    - run:
              name: Download sfdx
              command: |
                mkdir sfdx
                sudo wget -qO- https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz | tar xJ -C sfdx --strip-components 1
          - run:
              name: Install sfdx
              command: |
                ./sfdx/install
                sfdx
                mkdir tmp   
     - run: 
                 name: Create Hub
                 command: |
                     openssl enc -nosalt -aes-256-cbc -d -in access/server.key.enc -out access/server.key -base64 -K $DECRYPTION_KEY -iv $DECRYPTION_IV
                     sfdx force:auth:jwt:grant -i $HUB_CONSUMER_KEY -f ./access/server.key -u $HUB_SFDX_USER --setdefaultdevhubusername -a hub
          - run:
                 name: Create Org
                 command: |
                     venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev    
                     venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites robot/tests/Activities.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant sections from your CircleCI YML configuration?

Comment: I have added  CircleCI YML file in the question

Comment: Could you try setting `dev` as the default or after running `qa_org` flow? It should be: `venv/bin/cci org default dev`

Comment: Also, can you share more information about how you know it's creating a fresh org? Do you have build logs that show CCI's output during the build?

Comment: setting as default did not worked,   
 - run: 
             name: Create Hub
             command: |
                 openssl [...]
                 sfdx force[...]
                 venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev
                 venv/bin/cci org default dev                  
      - run:
             name:Run Robot Test
             command: |
                 venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites [...]

Comment: Yes in the in circleci logs,I can clearly see it is creating the org after pushing the code

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the logs

Comment: It's _supposed_ to create one org every time it runs. When `qa_org` runs, a blank scratch org will be created, then `qa_org` runs, then `robot` runs in the context of the same org. Are you expecting to use the same org across multiple CI runs?

Comment: I want to run my automation test on the org where I am pushing my code

Comment: OK, I see what you are talking about but I'm having a hard time interpreting where the first org creation comes from. (It's hard to see in the screenshot what step that is part of).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102868/discussion-between-pronit-agrawal-and-david-reed).

Comment: First Org is getting created at "venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev"
It seems org is not able to set as default even after "venv/bin/cci org default dev" command
second org is getting created at "venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites[..]" Ideally CCI Task run robot should not create an org if default org is present.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete explanation for this issue, but I think the information you've supplied gives a pretty good shot at pinning down where it is located.

CumulusCI appears to me to be working correctly, and you're running the correct commands.

The issue appears to me to lie in your CircleCI YML. The YML you've shared here does not match the screenshot, so it's hard to give a firm diagnosis. The screenshot, however, clearly shows your `cci flow run qa_org` command being run twice, once in the Create Hub step and once in the Create Org step. That's not your intent, and it's not correct.

A *possible* cause is that your YML file is indented incorrectly. You should ensure that your `- run:` steps all have the same indentation, as part of the same YML list. It is not immediately clear to me how this mistake will be interpreted by some YML parser and then subsequently by CircleCI, but it's a clear issue and might be the ultimate source of this confusing behavior.

However, the YML, again, does not match the screenshot, so it's hard to be 100% clear. I would fix the YML formatting first and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I have update the screenshot as per my YML, I am getting the same issue, first command i.e"venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev" this is creating new org and than pushing the code. second one "venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites robot/tests.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome" is creating new org than running the test cases.

Comment: Issue was with the "CUMULUSCI_KEYCHAIN_CLASS". check the link for more update https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290323/cumulusci-intermittent-keychain-error-observed-on-circleci/290354#290354