# CumulusCI: Intermittent Keychain Error Observed on CircleCI

Tags: salesforcedx, cumulusci

I'm trying to run CCI commands on CircleCI.

First command executes without issue:
`cci flow run qa_org --org dev`

Second command errors out:
`env/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites[..]`

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

[image]

```
- run:
    name: create org
    command: |
      venv/bin/cci flow run qa_org --org dev
- run:
    name: Run robot tests
    command: "venv/bin/cci task run robot --org dev -o suites robot/tests.robot -o include test -o vars LocalOrRemote:Local,Browser:googlechrome"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying this over from the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI/issues/1439https://):

1. Set the CUMULUSCI_KEY environment variable to a random 16-character string. CumulusCI uses this as an encryption key when writing files that store scratch org credentials. By default it creates a key and stores it in the system keychain. However, the error that @prescod noticed means that it is having trouble doing that, so it won't be able to store the org info. If you explicitly set CUMULUSCI_KEY, CumulusCI will use it instead of trying to generate and store a new one.
2. Don't set the CUMULUSCI_KEYCHAIN_CLASS environment variable to cumulusci.core.keychain.EnvironmentProjectKeychain (This makes CumulusCI load org config information from environment variables rather than from the filesystem, so it won't find files that were saved by a previous execution of cci.)

Comment: Thanks Brand, Solution has resolved the issue